# why does this code keep erroring on codeigniter

Tags: sql, codeigniter

```
public function semua_data1()
    {
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('tbl_m_stock');
        $tgl = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("-365 day", strtotime(date('Y-m-d'))));

        $this->db->join('tbl_t_purchase', 'tbl_m_stock.purchase_id = tbl_t_purchase.purchase_id', 'left');
        $this->db->where('tbl_t_purchase.create_date <', $tgl);
        $this->db->where('tbl_m_stock.stockin - tbl_m_stock.stockout >', 0);
        return $this->db->get();
    }
```

```
What is wrong?
```

Error Number: 1064

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '`tbl_m_stock`.`stockout` >0' at line 5

SELECT * FROM `tbl_m_stock` LEFT JOIN `tbl_t_purchase` ON `tbl_m_stock`.`purchase_id` = `tbl_t_purchase`.`purchase_id` WHERE `tbl_t_purchase`.`create_date` < '2022-01-26' AND `tbl_m_stock`.`stockin -` `tbl_m_stock`.`stockout` >0

Filename: D:/xampp/htdocs/SINARBANGUNAN07/system/database/DB_driver.php

Line Number: 691

Answer (score 0):

Because it's 2 different fields with an operator you need to parenthesis them.

```
 $this->db->where('(tbl_m_stock.stockin - tbl_m_stock.stockout) >', 0);
```

Should work